# How to get a form with fields built with ng-repeat to pass data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a simple form that allows a user to enter their traveler information in order to take a trip. The form is dynamically built depending on how many travelers you said you wanted to travel with you on a previous page.

The form below works for the first and last payment sections, but it does not work for any of the traveler information sections.  Form validation works, but I can't get any data from the input fields to pass over.

Here is the HTML code for the form that won't work, which is part of a bigger form):

```
    <span ng-repeat="travelerInfo in travelerData" ng-form="travelerForm_{{$index}}">
                        <div class="row"><!--row5-->
                            <h3 class="col-md-12" style="margin-left:15px;">{{travelerInfo.fn || 'Traveler'}} {{travelerInfo.ln || $index+1}} {{travelerInfo.sfx}}: {{travelerInfo.traveler_type}} ({{travelerInfo.age_group_range}})</h3>
                        </div><!--end of row5-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.first_name.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.first_name.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="first_name">First Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
                                    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" id="first_name_traveler_{{$index}}" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="travelerInfo.fn" required analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                </div><!--end of input group-->
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of first-name-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.middle_name.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.middle_name.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="middle_name">Middle Name</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
                                    <input type="text" name="middle_name" class="form-control"  id="middle_name_traveler_{{$index}}" placeholder="Middle Name" ng-model="travelerInfo.mn" analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of middle name-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.last_name.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.last_name.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="last_name">Last Name <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
                                    <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="travelerInfo.ln" required analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of last name-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><!--col3-->
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.suffix_traveler.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.suffix.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="suffix">Suffix</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
                                    <select name="suffix" class="form-control remove-corners" id="suffix_traveler_{{$index}}" ng-model="travelerInfo.sfx" analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                        <option></option>
                                        <option value="II">II</option>
                                        <option value="III">III</option>
                                        <option value="IV">IV</option>
                                        <option value="V">V</option>
                                        <option value="VI">VI</option>
                                        <option value="VII">VII</option>
                                        <option value="VIII">VIII</option>
                                        <option value="IX">IX</option>
                                        <option value="X">X</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of col3-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.birthday.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.birthday.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="birthday">Birthday<i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i></a>
                                    <input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthday_traveler_{{$index}}" class="form-control" ng-model="travelerInfo.birthday" max="{{travelerInfo.age_group_max | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" min="{{travelerInfo.age_group_min | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" required analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of last name-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><!--col3-->
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.gender.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.gender.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="suffix">Gender <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></i></a>
                                    <select name="gender" class="form-control remove-corners" id="gender_traveler_{{$index}}"  ng-model="travelerInfo.gender" required analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                        <option></option>
                                        <option value="Male"><i class="fa fa-male" ></i>Male</option>
                                        <option value="Female"><i class="fa fa-female"></i>Female</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of col3-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6"><!--col3-->
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.special.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.special.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="special">Special Request</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i></a>
                                    <select name="special" class="form-control remove-corners" id="special_traveler_{{$index}}" ng-model="travelerInfo.special" analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                        <option></option>
                                        <option>Blind Traveler - with guide dog</option>
                                        <option>Blind Traveler - without guide dog</option>
                                        <option>Deaf Traveler - with guide dog</option>
                                        <option>Deaf Traveler - without guide dog</option>
                                        <option>Meet And Assist - Elderly</option>
                                        <option>Meet And Assist - Handicapped</option>
                                        <option>Meet And Assist - Pregnant</option>
                                        <option>Wheelchair - All the way to seat</option>
                                        <option>Wheelchair - For ramp</option>
                                        <option>Wheelchair - Up and down stairs</option>
                                        <option>Wheelchair - On board</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of col3-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><!--col3-->
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.window_aisle.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.window_aisle.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="window_aisle">Window or Aisle</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a>
                                    <select name="window_aisle" class="form-control remove-corners" id="window_aisle" ng-model="travelerInfo.window_aisle" analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                        <option>No Preference</option>
                                        <option>Window</option>
                                        <option>Middle</option>
                                        <option>Aisle</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of col3-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><!--col3-->
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.meal_preference.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.window_aisle.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="meal_preference">Meal Preference</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i></a>
                                    <select name="meal_preference" class="form-control remove-corners" id="meal_preference_traveler_{{$index}}" ng-model="travelerInfo.meal_preference" analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                        <option>No Preference</option>
                                        <option>Diabetic</option>
                                        <option>Gluten Free</option>
                                        <option>Kasher</option>
                                        <option>Low Cholesterol</option>
                                        <option>Low Fat</option>
                                        <option>Low Sodium</option>
                                        <option>Muslim</option>
                                        <option>Vegan</option>
                                        <option>Vegitarian</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of col3-->
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6"><!--col3-->
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.frequent_flyer_airline.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.window_aisle.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="frequent_flyer_airline">Frequent Flyer Airline</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a>
                                    <select name="frequent_flyer_airline" class="form-control remove-corners" id="frequent_flyer_airline_traveler_{{$index}}" ng-model="travelerInfo.frequent_flyer_airline" analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                            <option></option>
                                            <option>Air Canada</option>
                                            <option>AirTran Airways</option>
                                            <option>Alaska Airlines</option>
                                            <option>American Airlines</option>
                                            <option>Delta Air Lines</option>
                                            <option>Frontier Airlines</option>
                                            <option>JetBlue</option>
                                            <option>Porter Airlines</option>
                                            <option>Spirit Airlines</option>
                                            <option>United Airlines</option>
                                            <option>US Airways</option>
                                            <option>Virgin America</option>
                                            <option>West Jet</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of col3-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.frequent_flyer_number.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.frequent_flyer_number.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="frequent_flyer_number">Ferequent Flyer Number</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><b>#</b></a>
                                    <input type="text" name="frequent_flyer_number" style="text-transform: uppercase;" class="form-control" id="frequent_flyer_traveler_{{$index}}" placeholder="Frequent Flyer Number" ng-model="travelerInfo.frequent_flyer_number" analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of frequent flyer number-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : exerciseForm.redress_number.$invalid && (!exerciseForm.redress_number.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="redress_number">Redress Number <a href="#" class="c-yellow" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#redress-modal"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg"></i></a></label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><b>#</b></a>
                                    <input type="text"  name="redress_number" style="text-transform: uppercase;" class="form-control" id="redress_number_traveler_{{$index}}" placeholder="Redress Number" ng-model="travelerInfo.redress_number" analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of last name-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : travelerForm_{{$index}}.number_pass.$invalid && (!travelerForm_{{$index}}.number_pass.$pristine || submitted)}">
                                <label for="number_pass">Number / Pass ID <a href="#" class="c-yellow" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#number-pass-modal"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg"></i></a></label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <a class="input-group-addon"><b>#</b></a>
                                    <input type="text"  style="text-transform: uppercase;" name="number_pass" class="form-control" id="number_pass_traveler_{{$index}}" placeholder="Redress Number" ng-model="travelerInfo.number_pass" analytics-on="blur" analytics-category="exercise-field">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of last name-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    </span>
```

The other parts of the form work fine and the data is passed over.

Here is the AngularJS code:

```
$scope.memberData   = {};
$scope.travelerInfo = {};
$scope.paymentInfo = {};

$scope.submitted = false;
$scope.exerciseHold = function (isValid) {
if (isValid) {
    $('#test-formdata').modal('show');

    } //end if isValid function
}; //end of isValid function
```

This shows a bootstrap modal that has all the data in so I can see it. The bootstrap model shows `memberData` and `paymentInfo` but does not show `travelerInfo`.

How can I get the traveler information working?

Answer (score 0):

It appears ng-repeat is being misused here. See the line below

```
<span ng-repeat="travelerInfo in travelerData" ng-form="travelerForm_{{$index}}">
```

The data array is `travelerData`, but your javascript is referencing `travelerInfo`, which is a single element of the travelerData array.

Try changing `$scope.travelerInfo = {};` to `$scope.travelerData = [];` and using `console.log($scope.travelerData);` to validate the contents of the array.